# Polygonize reclassified NDVI layer, how to remove sliver ploygons (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, ndvi, polygonize

I have calculated an NDVI layer, to create three categories (water, gravel, vegetation) that I can then polygonize. Now there is the issue that bright colored rocks and water have similar signatures, and are also classified as water. When I polygonize my raster layer, all these areas with similar signatures are also in the category of water polygons. How can I get rid of them, and only have my river as water polygons? I cannot delete them, I have to assign them to the other category (rock in this case)

Here is a picture to show the sliver polygons that are created.

[image]

Comment: Can you [Sieve](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasteranalysis.html#sieve) the raster prior to polygonizing it?